# Changing vectors that were already created

Tags: c++, vector

I am working on a project that draws the solar system. I create the planets only once in my main function.

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

SolarSystem app(argc, argv);// Create 1 Solar System
app.createPlanets();// Create the planets in the Solar System
app.run(); 

return 0; 
}
```

Here is my `createPlanets()` function that sets values for the `vector<Planet>planets;` vector.

```
void SolarSystem::createPlanets() const
{
                    //File for texture       /   Radius   / /     Orbit         / /Tilt angle
planets.push_back(Planet("images/Sun.jpg",     696,   696,   2500.0,    0.0,       0.0  ));//0
planets.push_back(Planet("images/mercury.jpg", 2.44,  2.44,  57910.0,   45740.0,   0.0  ));//1
planets.push_back(Planet("images/venus.jpg",   6.05,  6.05,  108200.0,  107464.0,  177.3));//2
planets.push_back(Planet("images/earth.jpg",   6.37,  6.34,  149600.0,  147102.0,  23.5 ));//3
planets.push_back(Planet("images/moon.jpg",    1.74,  1.73,  384.0,     383.0,     5.145));//4
planets.push_back(Planet("images/mars.jpg",    3.39,  3.37,  227940.0,  207425.0,  25.2 ));//5
planets.push_back(Planet("images/Jupiter.jpg", 69.90, 65.24, 778330.0,  740734.0,  3.1  ));//6
planets.push_back(Planet("images/neptune.jpg", 24.63, 24.08, 4504300.0, 4460608.0, 29.6 ));//7
planets.push_back(Planet("images/pluto.jpg",   1.15,  1.15,  5913520.0, 4475140.0, 29.6 ));//8
}
```

I'm creating a menu where the user can change the scale of the planets so they can be easily spotted (the real scale makes the planets really hard to be found). In order to change the size I would have to go into the vector and change the radius of each of the planet object in there.

Does anyone know how I could do this?
The display function below draws the planets each frame.

```
void SolarSystem::display(GLContextData& contextData) const
{   


if(showOrbitPath)
    displayOrbitPath();


//These variables set each planet's orbit and rotation speed 
                 //Sun  Mer   Ven    Ear   Moon  Mar   Jup   Nep  Plu   
double orbitS[] = {0.0, 4.15, 1.600, 1.00, 13.0, 0.40, 0.08, 0.006, 0.004};
double rotatS[] = {1.0, 0.50, 0.125, 30.0, 1.00, 30.0, 75.0, 40.00, 5.000};

//index counter for variables above
int i = 0;

//Vector iteration
for(std::vector<Planet>::iterator it = planets.begin(); it != planets.end(); ++it)
{   
    //If the planet being displayed is the sun
    if (i == 0)
    //Turn off shading
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    else //Turn the spot where the Sun is into a light Source
    {
        GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 };
        GLfloat pos[] = { 2500.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);  
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);

    }
    if (i == 4)//moon
    {
        it->displayPlanet(orbitCounter*orbitS[i], orbitCounter*rotatS[i], 
              planets[3].getMajorAxis(),planets[3].getMinorAxis());
    }
    else //Planets
        it->displayPlanet(orbitCounter*orbitS[i]*0, orbitCounter*rotatS[i], 0.0,0.0);

    i++;
}
//base counter used to calculate orbit and rotation speed   
orbitCounter+=0.05;
//89750.0 is what's necessary for the Pluto to orbit around the Sun once.
if (orbitCounter > 89750.0)
orbitCounter = 0.0; 
}
```

I want to add an if statement where I can say

```
int scale = 1;
if(changeScale)
    scale == 100;
```

then I would multiply the radius by the scale. If `changeScale` isn't set, the planets should remain the same size. if `changeScale` is selected that would increase the size of planets by 100.
Is there a way I can do this without having to draw the planets every frame? If that's not possible, how can I do this redrawing the planets every frame? I'm just not sure how I can modify the object inside my vector.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest that you keep the model data in tact and apply the scale to the viewing transform of that object separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `Planet`s within your `vector`. It would look something like this:

```
planets[index].member = new_val;
```

Or, if the variables are `private` and you have accessor methods,

```
planets[index].setMember(new_val);
```

So, if you want to change the radius, it would look something like one of the two following statements:

```
if (changeScale) {
    for (int i = 0; i < planets.size(); ++i) {
        planets[i].radius *= 100; // this
        planets[i].setRadius( planets[i].getRadius() * 100 ); // or this
    }
}
```

Or, you could use `iterator`s:

```
if (changeScale) {
    for (std::vector<Planet>::iterator it = planets.begin(); it != planets.end(); ++it) {
        (*it).radius *= 100; // this
        (*it).setRadius( (*it).getRadius() * 100 ); // or this
    }
}
```